# Javascript: how to send data from one page to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have the following code on a page

```
function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(7);
            if (customerMarker) customerMarker.setMap(null);
            customerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            closest = findClosestN(results[0].geometry.location,10);
            // get driving distance
            closest = closest.splice(0,5);
            calculateDistances(results[0].geometry.location, closest,5);
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

And I need to be able to post data from another page to trigger the codeAddress function and give the document.getElementById('address').value a value.

the form on the other page currently looks like:-

```
<form>
    <input id="address" type="text" class="locator-input"  placeholder="Please enter a location or postcode..." value=""></input>
    <button type="submit" class="locator-submit">Find a store</button>
</form>
```

I have attempted a few things but I must admit I am not very good with javascript and I cant seem to get anything to work for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you have any questions I will be more than happy to answer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is your file type where function codeAddress() is written? js or any other?  one solution is here whatever your file. <button type="button" class="locator-submit" onclick="codeAddress(document.getElementById('address').value);">Find a store</button>  function codeAddress(address) {  }

Comment: The file type is php I attempted to use var address = <?php $_POST['address'] ?>; but for some reason this didn't work?

Comment: OK. you should write address = '<?php echo $_POST['address'] ?>'; echo is missing

Comment: Ok I have echoed the value into the script and looked at the source code but for some reason its not pulling out the closest 5 results its just pulling out all of the results.
If I use the var address = document.getElementById('address').value; the script pulls out the closest 5 results to the address inputted.

Comment: one solution is possible for this take one hidden field in your file and set default value <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['address'] ?> id="address" /> and take value from this field.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's really a javascript issue, but rather an HTML one. The `action` of your `<form>` element should be the page where you have the javascript code for the Google Maps widget, and then use javascript to retrieve the value and feed it to Google Maps.

You could also have the submit button trigger a function to do so, and not use the `action` method or even load another page.